# Textfield to display number in REALTIME with CURRENCY FORMAT as you type IT. Exmple: 1,000.00

Tags: javascript, php, string, real-time, money-format

I have been trying to make this code to display textfield number in real-time currency format at you type it. But once the page is loaded, it give me an error message that say the following: Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double...

Please, can someone help me to fix the problem with the code. Below is my code.

```
            <input id="source" type="text" oninput="copyData('source', 'target')"  />
            
            <?php
            $num = '<span id="target" class="myDIV"></span>';
            $formattedNum = number_format($num, 2);
            echo $formattedNum;
            ?>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  function copyData(sourceId, targetId) {
                    var data = document.getElementById(sourceId).value;
                    document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = data; 
                  }
            </script>
```

Comment: You're mixing php and JavaScript. The php code runs on your server; the JavaScript runs at the client browser.

Comment: You should go read [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) first of all.

Answer (score 1):

- Use jquery mask money library as in
  [here](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney).
- You can find the
  example [here](https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/).
- Another example link is [this](https://codepen.io/saini3080/pen/MWyxwZV).

Snippet example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#maskmoney').maskMoney();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input id="maskmoney" name="mask_input" type="text">
```

Comment: please include an example in your answer, in case the github page is removed

Comment: @jonatjano example link is already there let me add another for you 

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Currency-Input-Filed-Mask-Plugin-maskmoney/

will create **codepan** link also for you

Comment: Here is example link 

https://codepen.io/saini3080/pen/MWyxwZV

Thanks

Comment: @GSAINI I took the liberty of creating a snippet from your codepen, you can remove it if you prefer to

Answer (score 0):

You can't have live update with PHP.
For this you'll need to use JS

PHP's `number_format(number, n)` can be replaced with JS's [`Number.toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
function copyData(sourceId, targetId) {
  var data = Number(document.getElementById(sourceId).value);
  document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = data.toFixed(2); 
}
```

```html
<input id="source" type="text" oninput="copyData('source', 'target')"  />
<span id="target" class="myDIV"></span>
```

---

You can go even further by using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) with `style: 'currency'` which will detect your user location and display the value in the user's regional format

```js
function copyData(sourceId, targetId) {
  var data = Number(document.getElementById(sourceId).value);
  document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(data); 
}
```

```html
<input id="source" type="text" oninput="copyData('source', 'target')"  />
<span id="target" class="myDIV"></span>
```